# Attaching an Si4703 to an Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

SparkFun sells an FM Tuner Board ([here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11083)) and provides code to work it.  However, neither libraries that I found in other places, nor the example code that they provided, worked.  I have checked the wiring multiple times and I am nearly certain that the fault is in the code but I can't find it.  Thanks...

ECC

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you've done so far: wiring, code used? And then describe precisely what you observe. Just saying "it does not work" cannot be considered a good description of a problem!

Comment: In the provided example code it says to wire the Si4703 to the Arduino like so:                             3.3V : VCC
GND : GND
A5 : SCLK
A4 : SDIO
D2 : RST  I did this and I tried using the Arduino Library provided ([here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11083)) and the example code provided.  When I upload the example code, it says "Initializing I2C and Si4703" and then does nothing more... When I use the library's example code ([here](http://www.doctormonk.com/2011/09/sparkfun-si4703-fm-receiver-breakout.html)),  it fails to start the "void loop()" (discovered by some debugging).

Comment: It stops at the "radio.powerOn"  Thanks (Sorry for going over)